# How do you reuse S3 buckets when deploying Lambdas with Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Recently we have adopted Serverless to handle the deployment of Lambda functions in our AWS environment, but for every unique function that is deployed, a new S3 bucket is created. This is inefficient and having a single bucket for every stack that Serverless creates would be ideal. Is there any way to do this from within the serverless.yml file? I have attempted the following yml file configurations for resources without any success.

1 - Listing the bucket as a resource to use in the yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ServerlessBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: serverless-test-bucket
```

Output:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Removing old service versions...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
............Serverless: Deployment failed!

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

     An error occurred while provisioning your stack: ServerlessBucket
     - serverless-test-bucket already exists.
```

2 - Attempting to reference the bucket in the yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ServerlessBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        Ref: serverless-test-bucket
```

Output:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Removing old service versions...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3...
Serverless: Updating Stack...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

     Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies
     [serverless-test-bucket] in the
     Resources block of the template
```

Comment: you want to utilize the same bucket for every lambda function? your question is not clear...

Comment: That is correct. I want one bucket to deploy every Lambda function rather than have a separate bucket for each one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been added in a recent release of Serverless, however that release breaks the deploy functionality on certain operating systems, so the release to go with is 1.1.0.

This is done inside the serverless.yml file by adding deploymentBucket as a field under provider. 
Example:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  deploymentBucket: bucketName
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
      -  "*"
      Resource: "*"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a functionality added to the serverless framework, but there is an a [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-deployment-bucket) that helps you to implement this feature, check it out.